# Class MyProject\Bundle\QuestionsBundle\Entity\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection does not exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a 500 internal error:

> Class MyProject\Bundle\QuestionsBundle\Entity\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection does not exist

I don't understand where it comes from, here is my request:

```
$sessionsdejeuxbyuser = $this->sessiondejeux_user_repository->findBy(array('user' => $user->getId()), array('created' => 'desc'), 1);
```

Here is my class: http://pastebin.com/ZkJjWraj

I have no idea where it comes from and Google doesn't give me any clues neither...

Comment: Can you also paste the code for this class: `MyProject\Bundle\QuestionsBundle\Entity\SessionDeJeux`?

Comment: I think you have some problem with your `namespace` and `use` declaration somewhere... I think it is looking for the `\Doctrine\Common\Collection\Collection` class not from the root but from `\MyProject\Bundle\QuestionsBundle\Entity` namespace

Comment: Here is my SessionDeJeux entity, sorry it is a bit the mess:
http://pastebin.com/7LEqhzH0

Comment: And a weird thing, is this works fine:

  $tmp = $this->sessiondejeux_user_repository->findBy(array('user' => $user->getId(), 'sessiondejeux' => $sessiondejeux->getId()), array('created' => 'desc'), 1);

Comment: I checked all the namespaces and use, I don't see anything :-(

Comment: Ok yes I found it, you were right @cram1010 I had in my SessionDeJeux entity (and at 3others places) this error. I don't know how I got this written in the code (you can see it in my SessionDeJeux entity on the top there). If anybody have a good grep command for my bash, to check everywhere I used this, it could be usefull for me!

Comment: Ok, I put the comment as an answer as it seems it was the right reason. I also suggested you a `grep` command. Please, set the answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some problem with your namespace and use declaration somewhere... I think it is looking for the `\Doctrine\Common\Collection\Collection` class not from the root but from `\MyProject\Bundle\QuestionsBundle\Entity` namespace.

As you suggest in the comments, you can search quickly when the wrong code is written using grep:

`grep -irn your_code src/MyProject/Bundle/QuestionsBundle/`

`i`: ignore case, if you don't want to be worried about this

`r`: recursive

`n`: print line number after the file name

Answer (score 0):

cram1010 has a big clue ! You need to import the namespace of the Collection class. By default, if you don't, PHP expects classes to belong to the current namespace.

The problem is on `setThematiques` method in `SessionDeJeux` class.

Why did you concatenate your namespace with the one for Collection ???

```
/**
 * Set thematiques
 *
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $thematiques
 */
public function setThematiques(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $thematiques)
{
    $this->thematiques[] = $thematiques;
}
```

The same for `setTags` :

```
/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $tags
 */
public function setTags(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $tags)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tags;
}
```

Comment: I remember concatenated it, like 3months ago when I started to play with symfony2, certainly because a namespace/use problem, but the error displayed by symfony2 was about the collection. Without the lack of experience, I certainly modified it because the error maybe looked like "wrong parameter, it should be [insert here what I wrote]". So I just followed the instructions!